# sqlalchemy search function on table as classmethod?

Tags: python, oop, sqlalchemy

Assuming i have a class that is called Customer that is defined in sqlalchemy to represent the customer table. I want to write a search method so that ...

```
results = Customer.search(query)
```

will return the results based on the method. Do I want to do this as a @classmethod?

```
@classmethod
def search(cls,query):
    #do some stuff
    return results
```

Can i use cls in place of DBSession.query?

```
DBSession.query(Customer).filter(...)
cls.query(Customer).filter(...)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just recently wrote some similar code, following [this reference](http://pyramid.chromaticleaves.com/simpleauth/).

```
class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    @classmethod
    def by_id(cls, userid):
        return Session.query(Users).filter(Users.id==userid).first()
```

So the answer to your first question appears to be "yes". Not sure about the second, as I didn't substitute cls for DBSession.

Comment: Link is inactive

Answer (score 9):

To use

```
cls.query
```

you have to assign a `query_property` to your model classes!

You probably want to use this in other model classes as well, so you might want to do that in your model Base class somewhere in your `model/__init__.py`:

```
Base.query = Session.query_property()
```

Then you can simply write:

```
cls.query.filter(...)
```

Note that you don't specify the Object to query for anymore, that is automatically done by using the `query_property` mechanism.