# How to use type hint with SQLAlchemy models?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's we have a model defined as a subclass of the declarative base:

```
class User(Base):
    name = Column(String)
```

Later, I define a function that returned a `User` and specify the returned type as a type hint:

```
def find_user(name: str) -> User:
    ...
    return user
```

When I try to use the `name` field of returned value as a string, the type system complains that it's a `Column`, not a string.
What can I do to add type hint in such cases?

Comment: you can convert it into string

Comment: Have you considered adding a search method to the model class? [sqlalchemy search function on table as classmethod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933877/sqlalchemy-search-function-on-table-as-classmethod)

Comment: [Relevant docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/mypy.html).

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks. Seems like the only option before SQLAlchemy 2.0 is to use the Mypy plugin which is considered legacy even before leaving the alpha stage.

Answer (score 1):

You could map a dataclass which will have appropriate hints ([docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/dataclasses.html)).

That way, you have the type hints from dataclass declaration, and you map to a SQLAlchemy column via the `metadata`.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

from sqlalchemy.orm import registry, relationship

mapper_registry = registry()

@mapper_registry.mapped
@dataclass
class User:
    __tablename__ = "user"
    __sa_dataclass_metadata_key__ = "sa"
    id: int = field(init=False, metadata={"sa": Column(Integer, primary_key=True)})
    name: str = field(init=False, metadata={"sa": Column(String, nullable=False)})
```

Comment: Can you explain why it's possible to assign `field` to variables of type `int` or `str` in this example?

Comment: [`dataclasses.field`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field) is just a helper function to give functionality to specific fields, in this case, we're blocking the fields `id` and `name` from being added the the autogenerated `__init__` function, and give them metadata that will be used by SQLAlchemy (via the `__sa_dataclass_metadata_key__` class var) to map to `Column`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [SQLModel](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/) that substitutes SQLAlchemy models with its own combination of SQLAlchemy and Pydantic models that are based on regular type annotations (like `id: int`).